# Fill custom fields when saving custom post types

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, custom-field

I have a Custom Post Type called "Report." It has some custom fields, including the name of the place where the post has been written.

I would like that when a user saves (or updates) the post from the admin interface, if he did not fill the place name, the system will fill in automatically on the basis of latitude/longitude (using reverse geocoding).

Which hook should I use?

Answer (score 1):

You would use "[save_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post)" hook. It will look something like this.

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'populate_empty_place' );

function populate_empty_place( $post_id ) {

    //verify post is not a revision
    if ( !wp_is_post_revision( $post_id )  && get_post_type($post_id) == 'report') {

        // Check for empty place
        // And popluate with your own value     
    }

}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I thought in the first place. Unfortunately, if I insert into the `if` the code `update_post_meta($post_id, 'nearby_place_name', 'New York');`, when the user tries to add a new report post (before saving it) the place name is set to `New York`.

Comment: you mean it replaces the user's added place?

Comment: No, as soon as the user clicks on "Add Report", so before he entered any data, the place name is set to `New York`.

Comment: Please update your question and particularly specify that you want to populate when add post is clicked not after the post is saved/updated. Is this field displayed through a metabox?

Comment: No, like I said in the original post, I want to populate the place when the user saves (or updates) the post. But with your solution, the place is populated _before that_, i.e. when the user clicks on "Add Report" (that is not what I want). Btw, yes, this field is displayed through a metabox.

Comment: Hey, you are mistaking some thing.. save_post is only triggered a post or page is created or updated. It does not trigger when you click on "Add post/cpt"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6722/discussion-between-m-r-and-user)